# Are there any Scrivener hotkeys for screenplay formatting?

Tags: software, screenwriting, scrivener

Perhaps we can start on the same page: Scrivener is super, super, super crummy. Unfortunately for me, I've imported a complete screenplay that was a Word document into Scrivener, and now I need to edit it into a industry standard screenplay. I'm going through the whole script systematically, but it would be considerably easier if I could select the scene headings, dialogue etc. with shortcut commands.

Answer (score 2):

Select the text: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> selects a sentence.

Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and either <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd> ... for scene headings, dialogue etc.